# How to check two variables in a condition in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script, which is working more or less.

I started a program and pressed some keys.

Depending on several factors the program show one of two screens.
If the screen is number 1 then it should only run to the end (title: 10-2013 2013.06.17. Screen x).
If the screen is number 2 then it should press another key and then run to the end  (title: 10-2013 2013.06.17. Screen y).

The screen titles are not simple titles but they depend on some input, so here is what I tried:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
; Wait for any of the two screens
WinWait,%5%-%1% - %2% - Screen

; If it is the second screen
MyTitle = %5%-%1% - %2% - Screen y

WinGetActiveTitle,title
If(title = MyTitle)
{
    ControlSend,Static39,{Esc},%5%-%1% - %2% - Screen y
    Sleep 2000
}

; Here are the common part again    
ExitProgram:
```

The condition does not work. If I try it like above it does not go inside the condition. If I use %title% then it says "invalid characters in variable name 10-2013 2013.06.17. Screen y".

**Solution**

Based on Robert's answer

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
WinWait,%5%-%1% - %2% - Screen

IfWinExist %5%-%1% - %2% - Screen y
{
    ControlSend,Static39,{Esc},%5%-%1% - %2% - Screen y
    Sleep 2000
}
```

Comment: To your syntactical problem: To check string equality, either use `IfEqual, var, value` or `if(var = %value%)`. Consequentially, when comparing two string variables, one always has to be inside percent signs.

Comment: I tried if(var = %value%) but gave me a similair error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for multiple windows, use ahk_group like this:

```
GroupAdd, GroupName, ahk_class AutoHotKey
GroupAdd, GroupName, ahk_class CalcFrame

WinWait, ahk_group GroupName
```

Then check for each window individually

```
IfWinExists, ahk_class AutoHotKey
{
 WinActivate
 Do your thing
}
Else IfWinExists, ahk_class CalcFrame
{
 WinActivate
 Do your thing
}
Return
```

You can do this with SetTitleMatchMode, 2 and parts of the title as well

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use ahk_class, I have to check the title. The class is changing with every run. But I will try the IfWinExists check.

Comment: @Biri You don't have to use the window class. Pretty much every command for selecting a window lets you choose between several options. If you're new to AHK, I can recommend always researching commands before using them. Take a look at [GroupAdd's documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm). There you'll find that you can instead of the ahk_class just specify the title.

Comment: Thanks, but the group is not important for me, neither the class. I was stuck at the if condition, but I'm checking now the IfWinExist function.

Comment: Biri, You can't check multiple windows with winwait unless you use groups. My last sentence was that you can use the groups both with ahk_class AND SetTitleMatchMode, 2, using a part of the title. Your script will never pass the WinWait, so focusing on the rest will be of no use...

Comment: I can check several windows with WinWait without groups, using SetTitleMatch 2. It works, it runs, it goes to the condition part. Otherwise I wouldn't try to focus on the condition if I never get to it.